# Fabric JS IText font fuzzy according to position

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am implementing canvas using Fabric JS, and found an interesting issue.

[image: Font fuzzy or crisp]

As can be seen in the picture, left text font is fuzzy and right one is crisp. That is, text becomes fuzzy on some places, while crisp on other places.

## Javascript code

```
var radius = 50;
var circle2 = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: Math.sqrt(3) * radius / 2,
    fill: '#FFF',
    opacity: 0.5
});

var text2 = new fabric.IText('Anant Jadhav ANANT dfds sdss sd...', {
    fontSize: 10,
    textAlign: "center",
    left: Math.sqrt(3) * radius / 2,
    top: Math.sqrt(3) * radius / 2,
    originX: "center",
    originY: "center",
    lineHeight: 12,
    fontFamily: 'SanFrancisco',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fill: '#FFF',
    opacity: 0.5
});

var element1 = new fabric.Group([myPoly, formatted], {
    left: 4 * radius,
    top: Math.sqrt(3) * 5 * radius / 2,
    originX: "center",
    originY: "center",
    //hasBorders: false,
    hasControls: false,
    hasRotatingPoint: false
});
canvas.add(element1);
canvas.renderAll();

var element2 = new fabric.Group([myPoly, formatted], {
    left: 2.5 * radius,
    top: Math.sqrt(3) * 6 * radius / 2,
    originX: "center",
    originY: "center",
    //hasBorders: false,
    hasControls: false,
    hasRotatingPoint: false
});
canvas.add(element2);
canvas.renderAll();
```

JS Fiddle can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Miron/24ph9o5x/).
Please anyone suggest me what could be problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is hard to say as long I don't know what are you doing for the first object. It might be the issue because you are using different opacity. Can you include full code of 2 group objects?

Comment: @Observer, they are same, not different. the object becomes fuzzy on the left position, and crisp on the right position while it moves.

Comment: check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w19kascL/  I am using your code and works fine. What library version are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem could be in object caching for your particular project.

Up to fabricjs 1.6.6 shapes get rendered every frame.
Since 1.7.0 this is no more true by default.
When text is across pixel is harder to read with small fonts, operating system hinting, and anti aliasing helps a lot. Those affect also canvas.
Those smoothed fonts are good for the particualar position they get created.

In your case once you create a group, a cached copy gets created.
A small canvas containing a picture of your hexagon and text is saved, later it gets only moved around.

The natural aliasing created for one position could look bad when you move your group in different positions. if you do not position it with mouse ( that moves pixel by pixel ) but with code is likely that you get across 2 pixels and what was antialiase with the first draw gets more and more fuzzy.

Since you are drawing simple shapes, you do not get so much of performance issue disabling it.

try to set up in your project this:

`fabric.Object.prototype.objectCaching = false;`

and try if something change.

More details here:

[Fabric Object Caching](http://www.fabricjs.com/fabric-object-caching)

Comment: That makes sense, Thanks.